# css which depends on a div tag value

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a website which uses SQL and php to generate a div block. This div block will have an associated number (the range of which will probably be 1 - 100). I need the CSS to display the div element in relation to the associated number (e.g. the associated number is the margin-left % value).

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to assign different classes with multiple if condition before printing

Comment: Will this number be assigned as a class or an ID to the div tag?

Comment: you may also use inline styles `<div style="margin-left:<?php ...magic... ?>">...</div>`

Comment: Without seeing any code it's tough to know exactly, but maybe add an inline style while creating the div? something like: `'<div id="'.i.'" style="margin-left:'.i.'%;"></div>'`

Comment: @TylerH - The div element will already has a different ID tag. I'm not sure where to put this information. Can I create a custom tag?

Comment: @user3457175 You cannot create custom tags in valid HTML markup. In order for you to know how to call the number in CSS, you'll need to know how the number will be stored/placed in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that $result is the number generated by php, you could write a script like this

```
<?php
$result = 1;
echo '<div style="margin-left:'.$result.'">Div content</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, set the div style to the width desired (over a maximum of 100)?

Hence if div A with an associated number of 50 comes up and your container is 200px then:

```
<?php
$calculated = (50/100)*200;
echo '<div id="A" style="margin-left:'.$calculated.';"></div>';
?>
```

Alternatively if you want to use it as percentage of container:

```
<?php
$calculated = 50;
echo '<div id="A" style="margin-left:'.$calculated.%';"></div>';
?>
```

Hope that helps!